# How to ignore a Task in F#?

Tags: f#

If we have a function `f` that returns `Async<something>`, we can ignore the return value with `do! f() |> Async.Ignore`. Is there a similar construct for ignoring Tasks? Right now, I'm having to do something like this:

```ml
task {
    let! result = SomeOperation()
    result |> ignore
}
```

Technically I could do `|> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.Ignore`, but I'm not sure how wasteful it is to convert a task to async just to ignore it...

If it matters, I'm using `task{}` computation expressions from Ply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wait for a task to complete using the [`Result`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?view=net-6.0) property:

```
let t = 
    task { 
        let! _ = SomeOperation()
        ()
    }
let _ = t.Result
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care for the return value, then you don't have to wait for the task to finish, you can just ignore the whole task:

```
SomeOperation() |> ignore
```

Comment: I want to wait until the operation is finished, though. I just don't care about the return values.

Comment: The snippet you posted does not wait, unless you include it in some wider CE, which you did not post. The way to wait for a task but ignore the result would depend on why you need to wait for a task. That is, what are you going to do with it's finished.

Comment: Moreover, this is dangerous code because it could lead to unpredictable results, ones function returns value that asynchronous execution could be terminated at any time. I faced that already when, by mistake, used ignore for task

Answer (score 0):

If your function returns Async, then simply ignoring it won't work because unlike `Task`s, an `Async` operation does not execute unless you explicitly start it.

If you just want to make it run, but don't care about waiting until it is done you can do

```
f() |> Async.RunAsTask |> ignore
```

if you do want to wait for the result, you can do

```
f() |> Async.RunSynchronously |> ignore
```

Comment: The function definitely returns a `Task`. Look: it's being `let!`-bound in a `task` CE.

Comment: the question clearly states ` f that returns Async<something>`. So it definitely does not return a task. In an aside OP states that he's using Ply which probably supports both Async and Task in the task computation expression. But I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be defining Task.Ignore function similar to Async.Ignore:

```
type Task
with static member Ignore(f) = task { let! _ = f in return () }
```

so that your code would look like:

```
task {
    do! SomeOperation() |> Task.Ignore
}
```