# Proper way to use the do! keyword to await a Task<'a>

Tags: f#, task

I'm using F# to interoperate with async C# classes.

I have a case where I need to call a method that returns a generic `Task<'a>`, and asynchronously wait for it to complete, and then ignore the result.

By using the F# docs I learned that you can just use `do!` to await a non-generic `Task`.

```fs
task {
    do! obj.workAsync() // where workAsync: () -> Task
}
```

That's great. But when the signature of `workAsync` is `() -> Task<'a>`, the above doesn't work.

So I need some way to turn a `Task<'a> -> Task` and I came up with two ways (there may be more that I don't know about).

```fs
// variant 1
let toNonGenericTask (res: Task<'a>) : Task =
    task {
        let! _ = res
        ()
    }

// variant 2
let toNonGenericTask (res: Task<'a>) : Task =
    res.ContinueWith(fun (_: Task<'a>) -> ())


let processStuff () =
    task {
        do! obj.workAsync() |> toNonGenericTask // both variants work!
    }
```

My question is, which version of the `toNonGenericTask` function is to be preferred? Is there some other way to do the same thing without using a custom helper function?

---

Update after considering the helpful responses.

I didn't need to use a helper function after all. By simply adding an upcast, I'm able to wait for the generic task value asynchronously, while wrapping it in another task object which was what I needed to do.

It's quite readable and succinct.

```fs
task {
    do! obj.workAsync() :> Task
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Task<T>` derives from `Task`, you can simply upcast it to non-generic class:

```ml
let toNonGenericTask (t: Task<'a>) = t : Task

let foo () = task {
    let t = Task.FromResult 5
    do! t :> Task // upcast
    do! t : Task // specify type
    do! t |> toNonGenericTask // helper function, but it's too verbose in my opinion
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call `workAsync()` with `let! _ = ...`, as you do in the first example:

```
let processStuff () =
    task {
        let! _ = obj.workAsync() // this works too!
    }
```

Comment: This causes a compile error saying "error FS0010: Unexpected symbol '}' in expression ..."
When I add a `()` at the end, after the `let!` line, it works.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a task expression to work with a `Task`, and you don't need to map a `Task<'T>` to `Task` or order to ignore the result.

```
// Task
let task = obj.workAsync()
task.Wait()
```

or

```
// Task<'T>
let task = obj.workAsync()
task.Result // |> ignore if you don't care
```

Comment: Won't `task.Wait()` and `task.Result` block the main thread?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I was working off this at the top of your question: "I have a case where I need to call a method that returns a generic Task<'a>, wait for it to complete, and then ignore the result."

Comment: So what you really want is the task equivalent of Async.Ignore. Check out the answers in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71093379/how-to-ignore-a-task-in-f

Comment: Exactly. A non-blocking way to wait for a generic task to complete, but ignoring the actual result. I updated my question to reflect that I need to wait for the result asynchronously.